# How to get data json

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I would like to get Json data with JQUERY but my variable is undefined.

```
        var itech_centre='';
      
    $.each(data, function(key,value){
    
        itech_centre+='<tr>';
        itech_centre+='<td>'+value.c_com_nom+'</td>';
        itech_centre+='<td>'+value.c_adr_voie+'</br>'+value.c_com_cp+'</br>'+value.c_com_nom+'</td>';
        itech_centre+='<td>'+value.c_rdv_tel+'</td>';
        
        itech_centre+='</tr>';
    });
    
    $('#centreVaccination').append(itech_centre);
   
    
    });
```

This is my HTML

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="centreVaccination">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Centre</th>
                                <th>Adresse</th>
                                <th>Tel</th>
                                
                            </tr>
```

and my link JSON : https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/r/d0566522-604d-4af6-be44-a26eefa01756

thank you for you help!

Comment: I don't see any attempt to load JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see how you're setting `data`. Just setting the json in that link to `data` won't work because the values you're trying to get (`c_com_nom`, etc) are nested underneath a `features` array and inside a `properties` object.

I would approach this by creating a var to hold the `features` array and then loop through each feature and grab the attributes you want out of the properties object.

Example (slightly pseudocode-ish):

```
// Import json here
const features = data.features;
let rows = "";
features.forEach(feature => {
  let row = "<tr>";
  row += "<td>" + feature.properties.c_com_nom + "</td>"
  // ...
  row += "</tr>";
  rows += row;
}
// Append rows to your table
```